# Spark Streaming Issue. ( JAVA )

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to run a network word count job using spark streaming. The code is as below:

```
public class myclass {
public static Iterator<String> myfunc(String s){
    String ar[]=s.split(" ");
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String a:ar){
        l.add(a);
    }
    return l.iterator();
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("trial");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf,Durations.seconds(1));
JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 7777);
JavaPairDStream<String,Integer> tup=lines.flatMap(s -> myfunc(s)).mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<String,Integer>(s,1)).reduceByKey((a,b)-> a+b);
tup.print();
jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
jssc.stop();
jssc.close();
}
```

}

I ran this job using the command :

```
spark-submit --class myclass --master local <myjar.jar>
```

In another terminal I ran a local server as :

```
nc -lk 7777
```

The job runs fine, but it keeps going on and on..

It keeps on adding a new job for each millisecond. I tried adding lines on the local server it shows no error whatsoever but still the job goes on and on & output is shown.

I went through some online tutorials where with the same code, the result of the code is shown regularly like below :

```
time 14500000ms
__________________
<output>
```

But that doesn't happen in my case , it keeps on adding jobs like below :

```
Added jobs for time 1450000
Added jobs for time 1460000
Added jobs for time 1470000
. . . . 
. . . .
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Basic question: do you type anything in window that has `nc`  running?

Comment: @T.Gawęda " I tried adding lines on the local server it shows no error whatsoever but still the job goes on and on & output is shown. "